# In a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, can $X$ have indistinguishable elements?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I'm coming back to Group Theory after 20+ years out of it, and thus my vocabulary is a bit rusty. I'll try to express my problem the best I can.

Consider a group G acting on a set X. What I want is to let some elements of X to be indistinguishable. My guess is that it should be some quotient, but I don't know how to exactly define it.

For example, I have the group $G$ generated by $a=(1,2,3,4)$ and $b=(2,7,6,5)$. That's two circles intersecting at point 2 that can only rotate. I can express any element of $G$ as a word of $a$ and $b$. My problem is:

Now imagine points 1, 3 and 4 being of color blue. I want to express an element of $G$ as a word of $a$ and $b$ but I don't care where 1, 3 and 4 move as long as they fall on a blue position again. That is: elements 1, 3, and 4 are indistinguishable as far as color matters.

How can I define that? Am I talking about stabilizers? Isotropy? Some kind of quotient? Where can I read further to find what I am looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by a group generated by a quadruplet?

Comment: Look up free group

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai it's not a quadruplet. It's a cycle. So my example is subgroup of the permutation group $S_7$.

Comment: Stabliser is correct. You want $\operatorname{Stab}\{1, 3, 4\}$, the subgroup of all elements of $G$ that map $\{1, 3, 4\}$ within itself.

Comment: @TheoBendit, thanks!! I'll explore that!